# How to get total memory size of a device in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I needed the following data of an android/ios device through my flutter app.

1. Total memory size
2. Free Memory size
3. RAM size

How can I get it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `system_info` plugin to get information about system including total and free size of physical and virtual memory. You can get more detail in [here](https://pub.dev/packages/system_info).

```
// values are in byte  
print(SysInfo.getTotalPhysicalMemory());
print(SysInfo.getFreePhysicalMemory());
print(SysInfo.getTotalVirtualMemory());
print(SysInfo.getFreeVirtualMemory());
print(SysInfo.getVirtualMemorySize());
```

For getting storage space you can use `disk_space` plugin from [here](https://pub.dev/packages/disk_space):

```
// values are in MB 
print(await DiskSpace.getFreeDiskSpace);
print(await DiskSpace.getTotalDiskSpace);
```

Comment: I tried it out ....... My device has 6 GB ram and 60 GB  internal  storage ....... So the getTotalPhysicalMemory() is providing me correct value of my RAM (5.932..) ...... But how can I get the internal storage space ?

Comment: I've updated my answer, check it again @SarveshDalvi

Comment: I've got 64 GB internal storage and on printing the output of getTotalDiskSpace() it gives me this value : 50287.5703125   ...... Is this wrong or maybe its in a different unit ?

Comment: I think the output has a different unit than what I'm expecting ......... Can I know the unit of the output provided by the above functions ?

Comment: `(bytesAvailable / (1024f * 1024f)).toDouble()` this is the native android code used in this plugin. It's returning value in Megabytes @SarveshDalvi

Comment: I thought of it and hence divided it again by 1024 to get the output in GB ...... Then I'm getting 49.1 GB as final result ......... But my total storage space is 64 GB ..... What is happening here ?

Comment: This plugin is using external storage directory to compute the size and it's the part of the storage available for user (then storage reserved by system does not count here) @SarveshDalvi

Comment: This plugins does not support iOS I don't see why this was accepted as an answer is there any alternatives that do support iOS?

Comment: `system_info` plug-in is now marked "discontinued."